# Solution of $\phi \left( x \right) = f{\left( x \right)^{g\left( x \right)}}$

Tags: functions

Find the solution of ${\left( {{x^2} - 7x + 11} \right)^{\left( {{x^2} - 13x + 42} \right)}} = 1$

My approach is as follow $\phi \left( x \right) = f{\left( x \right)^{g\left( x \right)}}$

Case 1: $f\left( x \right) = 1;x = 2,5$

Case 2: $f\left( x \right) \ne 0;g\left( x \right) = 0;x = 6,7\& f\left( 6 \right) \ne 0;f\left( 7 \right) \ne 0$

Case 3: $f\left( x \right) =  - 1;g\left( x \right) =$ even ;$x = 3,4\& f\left( 3 \right) = 12;f\left( 4 \right) = 6$

I have one doubt in Case 3, I am analysing the case $x^x$, in such scenario $x>0$.

Also if $y=a^x$, then if $a=0,x \in R-0$ and $a>0$

$\phi \left( x \right) = f{\left( x \right)^{g\left( x \right)}}$ is also a type of exponential function, they I presume that f(x) is not negative so why they have taken $f(x)=-1$ for case 3, please elaborate

Comment: Are you really taking the position that $(-1)^2$ cannot be evaluated?

Comment: I just need to confirm, I have elaborated the case,

Comment: Suppose $f(x)^{g(x)} = 1$.  Then if $|f(x)| > 1$, we must have $g(x) = 0$; if $|f(x)| < 1$, we must have $g(x) = 0$; and if $|f(x)| = 1$ either $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x)$ is anything or $f(x) = -1$ and $g(x)$ is an even integer (of either sign).

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi It was explained in this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/C7A3uFC76G0), unless you got this question from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left ( x^2-7x+11 \right )^{\left ( x^2-13x+42 \right )}=1\Leftrightarrow \left ( x^2-7x+11 \right )^{\left ( x^2-13x+42 \right )} =\left ( x^2-7x+11 \right )^0$$
$$\left ( x^2-7x+11-1 \right )\left ( x^2-13x+42 \right )=0\Leftrightarrow \left ( x^2-7x+10 \right )\left ( x^2-13x+42 \right )=0$$
$$x^2-7x+10=0\Rightarrow x=\left \{ 2,5 \right \}$$
$$x^2-13x+42=0\Rightarrow x=\left \{ 6,7 \right \}$$
You need to check the roots:
$$x^2-7x+11>0$$
All four roots fit!

Answer (score 1):

Eric is correct, but you need to exclude the case where $|f(x)|=0$, because $0^{0}$ is indeterminate form. $f(x)$ can be negative, as long as $g(x)$ makes $\phi(x)$ defined and real, in our case as long as $g(x)$ (even).